# Where to rent a motorcycle in Nakhon Ratchasima (Korat)?

Tags: thailand

I reside in Bangkok and I think to take a train to nearby Nakhon Ratchasima (Korat), just to spend there a day or two and travel in the city, get impressed from its urban planning, real estate, sites and restaurants; to randomly travel in the city a bit. I think I would prefer to do so with a motorcycle.

My budget is up to 250 THB for a motorcycle per day; a simple automatic scooter is likely to be handy for me as long as it is whole and safe.

Where to rent a motorcycle in Nakhon Ratchasima (Korat)?

Comment: Are you asking for a specific shop? If so, this will be off topic. Are you looking for a general location? If so, I think we need more precise information, like which station you will arrive at. And remember, using a motorized two wheeler is not safe even when the machine is in good condition. It is the rider and the road conditions which can make it less safe.

Comment: @Willeke using any mode of transport is "*not safe*".  People can fall under trains and buses, or try to board when they're moving and come to harm; airplanes expose one to higher levels of ionising radiation; cars are equally subject to the vagaries of driver skill and road conditions.  I accept that PTWs (Powered Two-Wheelers) are generally *less* safe than cars in terms of KSI per passenger-kilometre, but that doesn't make them uniquely "*not safe*", and it particularly doesn't make them qualitatively differently so from other forms of transport.